# Why is an SMTP service running by default after the install?

Tags: linux, smtp

I can see that localhost:25 is by default used after an install on many Linux distributions.

Why is this for?

My hint is for to deliver local system-generated mails?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that by default a SMTP server is up and running in a new Linux install is for the system to deliver important notifications and other information (status of cron jobs, etc.) to the root user.

Don't worry however -- for security reasons, the SMTP server is configured to accept mail from localhost only, so not to be an open mail relay.